Proving the Basis of a Scaled Vector Set J
If $ E = \left\{\overrightarrow{e_1}, \overrightarrow{e_2}, \overrightarrow{e_3}\right\} $ is a basis, prove that $ F = \left\{\alpha \overrightarrow{e_1}, \beta \overrightarrow{e_2}, \gamma \overrightarrow{e_3}\right\} $ is a basis, provided that $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma $ are non-zero.
Attempt: Note that if $\alpha, \beta, \lambda$ are non-zero, then we can express $ \overrightarrow{e_1}, \overrightarrow{e_2}, \overrightarrow{e_3} $ in terms of $ \alpha \overrightarrow{e_1}, \beta \overrightarrow{e_2}, \gamma \overrightarrow{e_3} $
$$
\overrightarrow{e_1} = \frac{1}{\alpha} (\alpha \overrightarrow{e_1}), \quad \overrightarrow{e_2} = \frac{1}{\beta} (\beta \overrightarrow{e_2}), \quad \overrightarrow{e_3} = \frac{1}{\gamma} (\gamma \overrightarrow{e_3})
$$
Any vector $\overrightarrow{v} $in space can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors from $ F $
$$
\overrightarrow{v} = a_1 \frac{1}{\alpha} (\alpha \overrightarrow{e_1}) + a_2 \frac{1}{\beta} (\beta \overrightarrow{e_2}) + a_3 \frac{1}{\gamma} (\gamma \overrightarrow{e_3})
$$
question: Is this a sufficient argument?
